# Getting Error: no such column for values inserted

Tags: sqlite

I am just learning the first steps of SQLite and I am trying to create a small database and I always get the error message - Error: no such column: "Duisburg".
Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot.

sqlite> CREATE TABLE Wohnort (PLZ int, Wohnort varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (PLZ));

sqlite> INSERT INTO Wohnort (PLZ, Wohnort) VALUES (45472,“Mülheim“),(58674,“Köln),(47137,“Duisburg“);

Error: no such column: “Duisburg“

Comment: You missed the closing quote for `Köln`.

Comment: Right sorry! But the error is displayed to me...

Comment: And you should be using single quotes, not double. The latter are used to quote table and column names, not strings, in SQL.